# PIL image save causes FFMPEG to fail

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library

I have been attempting to convert some videos using FFMPEG with image2pipe using PIL. I have found that when the frame is particularly simple (such as all one colour), it causes FFMPEG to fail with the following message:

```
[image2pipe @ 000001785b599bc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none, none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, image2pipe, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: none, none, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to '<YOUR FILEPATH HERE>/test.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

The minimum code I have found to reproduce this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from PIL import Image

output_file = "<YOUR FILEPATH HERE>/test.mp4"

p = Popen(['ffmpeg',
           '-y',  # Overwrite files
           '-f', 'image2pipe',  # Input format
           '-r', '24',  # Framerate
           '-i', '-',  # stdin
           '-c:v', 'libx264',  # Codec
           '-preset', 'slow',
           '-crf', f'18',  # H264 Constant Rate Factor (quality, lower is better)
           output_file], stdin=PIPE)

# This one works
# vid = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10, 64, 64))  # Create a 64x64 'video' with 10 frames of random noise

# This one does not
vid = np.full((10, 64, 64), 129)  # Create a 64x64 'video' with 10 frames of pure grey

for frame in vid:
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(frame))
    im.save(p.stdin, 'JPEG')

p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Notably, if I do the same thing with a randomly generated series of frames (commented as "This one works" in the script above), it will output fine.

One workaround I have found so far is to replace 'JPEG' with 'PNG' in the `im.save(...)` call. However, I would be interested in understanding what causes it to fail with JPEG.

Comment: Try changing `-r 24` to `-framerate 24` and adding `-r 24` as the penultimate parameter to `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Surely your frames should be RGB, i.e. with shape (10,64,64,3)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the suggestion! I tried switching to `-framerate 24` and putting `-r 24` penultimately, but that hasn't appeared to change anything. The application I'm using this for happens to use greyscale images, hence the greyscale example.

Comment: Maybe you need to tell `ffmpeg` that the frames are JPEG with something like `-vcodec mjpeg` before the `-i` parameter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Interesting, that works, thank you! Does this suggest that ffmpeg otherwise fails to infer that it is a JPEG due to the simplicity of the frame?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. We're going to need someone who knows more about `ffmpeg` and is willing to explain things but sadly many of the answers don't go into any detail.